# Fluid TYPO3 Translate Text in Page Template

Tags: templates, typo3, translate, fluid

I work with `TYPO3 6.2.12` and the latest [FluidTYPO3-Extensions](https://github.com/FluidTYPO3). I also have a Multilanguage-Website (german/english).

At my Page-Template `Subpage.html` I need a headline in english (`mydomain.de/en/page.html`) and also in german (`mydomain.de/de/seite.html`). But I don't know why?!

```
<h3 class="section-heading">Manufacturers</h3>
```

and for the german users ...

```
<h3 class="section-heading">Hersteller</h3>
```

I've made it with the file `locallang.xlf` and `de.locallang.xlf` (s. below and thanks to jost answer 1). But how's the syntax for my template?

My tries doesn't work .. cleared caches?!

```
<h3 class="section-heading"><f:translate key="LLL:typo3conf/ext/redeagle/Resources/Private/Language/locallang.xlf:navigation.sub.headline" /></h3>
```

or

```
 <h3><f:translate key="navigation.sub.headline"/></h3>
```

Need a bit of help to show the Text from `locallang.xlf`at my template. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The xliff format is described [here](http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/Internationalization/Introduction/Index.html).

You need to have one file for the default labels, e.g. `locallang.xlf`. Then you add another file for each translation, with the language code prepended to the file name of the file with the default labels. In the example it could be `de.locallang.xlf`. This file has to be in the same folder the `locallang.xlf` is located.

This file is a copy of the file with the default labels, but with some additions:

1. The `<file>` tag gets an additional attribute `target-language` with the language code of the translation as value.
2. Each `<source>`-tag gets a `<target>` tag as sibling, containing the translation of the label.

Make sure you clear the caches (in the install tool) after changing translations, so you can see the changes.

A translation program for XLIFF is [virtaal](http://virtaal.translatehouse.org/), works quite well for me.

In your example, you should have these two files:

**locallang.xlf:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<xliff version="1.0">
    <file source-language="en" datatype="plaintext" original="messages"
          date="2012-10-17T17:55:17Z" product-name="myproject">
        <header/>
        <body>
            <trans-unit id="flux.sidebar.navigation.sub.headline">
                <source>Manufacturer</source>
            </trans-unit>
        </body>
    </file>
</xliff>
```

**de.locallang.xlf:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<xliff version="1.0">
    <file source-language="en"  target-language="de" datatype="plaintext" original="messages"
          date="2012-10-17T17:55:17Z" product-name="myproject">
        <header/>
        <body>
            <trans-unit id="flux.sidebar.navigation.sub.headline">
                <source>Manufacturer</source>
                <target>Hersteller</target>
            </trans-unit>
        </body>
    </file>
</xliff>
```

Comment: Hi Jost, thanks for the explaining. Got it. But how is the syntax at my template? `<h3 class="section-heading">???</h3>`

Comment: You missed the `flux.` prefix of the label name. You can also leave out the file path in the key if the language file is in the default location in the same extension. Also use the `id`-attribute instead of the `key`-attribute, the latter one is depreciated (but should still work). This should work: `<f:translate id="flux.sidebar.navigation.sub.headline"/>`, this too: `{f:translate(id: 'flux.sidebar.navigation.sub.headline')}`.

Comment: Thanks jost ... i've got it. see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Got it.

My default Language is "german", the second language is "english"

locallang.xlf

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<xliff version="1.0">
    <file source-language="de" datatype="plaintext" original="messages" product-name="project1" date="2015-05-05T12:31:24+02:00">
        <header/>
        <body>

            <trans-unit id="flux.subsidebar.navigation.sub.headline" xml:space="preserve">
                <source>Hersteller</source>
            </trans-unit>

        </body>
    </file>
</xliff>
```

en.locallang.xlf

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<xliff version="1.0">
    <file source-language="de" target-language="en" datatype="plaintext" original="messages" product-name="project1" date="2015-05-05T12:31:24+02:00">
        <header/>
        <body>

            <trans-unit id="flux.subsidebar.navigation.sub.headline" xml:space="preserve">
                <source>Hersteller</source>
                <target>Manufacturer</target>
            </trans-unit>

        </body>
    </file>
</xliff>
```

And at my fluid-template

```
<h3><f:translate key="flux.subsidebar.navigation.sub.headline"/></h3>
```

Perfect! Thanks to Jost. I only had time for one night sleep over it...